# Proposed limit proofs

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, limits, proof-verification

I have a question regarding an approach to finding the limit of a function:

Consider the function $$f(x) = x^{2}\sin(\frac{1}{x})~~~\text{for }x \neq 0~~~\text{and }f(0) =1$$

Show that $\lim\limits_{x \rightarrow 0,x \in \mathbb{R}}f(x)$ does not exist.

I will use a result I found in the wiki entry 'first-countable spaces' which states: If $f$ is a function on a first-countable space then $f$ has a limit $L$ at the point $x$ if and only if for every sequence $x_{n} \rightarrow x$ where $x_{n} \neq x$ for all $n$ we have $f(x_{n}) \rightarrow L$.

If I want to prove that $\lim\limits_{x \rightarrow 0, x \in \mathbb{R}}f(x)$ does not exists, I have the following two proposed ideas, the first is:

1. Define the sequence $x_{n} = 0$ when $n =2k-1$ for $k \geq 1$ and $x_{n} = \frac{1}{n}$ when $n = 2k$. Then this sequence converges to $0$ but $f(x_{2k})$ converges to $0$ while $f(x_{2k-1})$ converges to $1$. Therefore the limit does to exists by wiki result.
2. The second idea is similar to the first but I consider the two sequences separately. So consider sequences $x_{n} = 0$ and $y_{n} = \frac{1}{n}$. Then $f(x_{n}) \rightarrow 0$ and $f(y_{n}) \rightarrow 1$. By wiki result it follows that the limit does not exists.

I'm pretty sure that proposed answer 1 is fine. As for 2. I'm not sure if we can consider the sequence $x_{n} = 0$ as it is stated that the result holds only for $x_{n} \neq x$ for all $n$.

What do you think?

Comment: use that $|x^2\sin(1/x)|\le x^2$

Comment: Wait, that limit *does* exist and equals zero. You are trying to prove a false statement.

Comment: @FedericoPoloni The limit definitely does not exist.

Comment: Let's get this sorted out. I'll use your result on first countable spaces. For each sequence $x_n\to 0$ (with $x_n\neq 0$ for each $n$), we have $-x_n^2 \leq x_n^2\sin(1/x_n) \leq x_n^2$, so by the squeeze theorem $f(x_n)\to 0$. I believe that this is a full proof; let me know if I am wrong. The value of $f(0)$ is irrelevant for the limit.

Comment: I agree with Federico Poloni, the limit does exist and is equal to $0$. Although the function is certainly not continuous at $0$

Comment: I concur, the limit can be proven by the squeeze theorem to equal zero..

Answer (score 1):

I think those were both really solid first steps toward attempting to prove the limit does not exist. Unfortunately, the technical conditions are not on your side:

- As you observed, the wiki result you quoted does not suffice to complete your proposed second idea, since you cannot have $x_n=x$.
- (edited) The same problem blocks the wiki result from completing the first proposed idea as well.

Obligatory helpful comment: Do you know what the graph of $f$ looks like? ([This](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=f%28x%29%3Dx%5E2*cos%281%2Fx%29%20for%20x%E2%89%A00%2C%20f%28x%29%3D1%20for%20x%3D0) is not quite your function, but it is for all values except $x=0$).

Comment: Thanks for your response. With regard to your second point, I was using the wiki result for the first proposed idea. I constructed a sequence $x_{n} \rightarrow 0$ such that $x_{n} \neq x$ for all $n$ and where $f(x_{n})$ cannot converge to $f(0) = 1$. So then using the wiki result it follows that the limit $\lim\limits_{x \rightarrow 0}f(x)$ cannot exist.

Comment: @Alex: Ah, I see. I did not actually read the result you quoted, I just assumed I knew what it said :/ The statement as you have written it is false; it is true if you replace $f(x)$ with $L$. However, I might note that even then you did not satisfy the technical restriction: I think you read $\lnot (\forall n, x_n=x)$ but what is intended is $\forall n,\ x_n\neq x$.

Comment: Oh yeah I see, I corrected that typo. I am reading it as $x_{n} \neq x ~~ \forall n$ but that it is fine for some $n$, so I see that as saying that it applies to any nonconstant convergent sequence. So the first proof should satisfy that. But you are saying that no $x_{n}$ can be equivalent to $x$.

Comment: Yeah, you got it. That is a fairly common mistake (actually a mistake by the writer for failing to realize the ambiguity!)